# USB Card-Reader is not recognized?

Tags: usb

It's an USB 3.0 Card Reader, which I try to use on Windows7, other usb3 devices work well.
And on Linux the Card Reader works well.

What might it be ?

Thanks

Comment: Missing/unrecognizable Windows partition? Does the device show up under Disk Management tool?

Comment: Does it make a difference whether a card is inserted or not?

Comment: On win7 it's not recognized, with or without sd-card inserted. On Linux/Debian it's recognized with the sd-card inserted. No the Device is not showed under the partitions. I tried to see something on the Hardware-logs, with nothing.

Comment: Does the USB device appear in USBview.exe utility?

Comment: I found another tool "usbdeview" and it shows the device was pluged in but not connected. There some more informations about, like power, id and so on.

Comment: Now it seems to work, suddently. Perhaps it was a Windows-Update to bring the right Device-driver. Thanks